# Relation betweenn hibernate and spring

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a question about spring + hibernate
I always use hibernate for my develeppoment, I generate images of the tables and the class DAO
then at logic metier I make simple calls to these methods dao ....

> for exemple UserDao=new UserDao () then userdao.persist() ...

Now I have intgret spring, and I do not yet understand ..

1

> what is the plus made ​​by him knowing that he is also making calls
>   has dao Service (the writings that manually) it does not generate the
>   class dao with hibernate

2

> is that with spring I would not worry about manage session for
>   example open session, close session commit() ...

thank you in advance I would like to have an idea Ccool:

Answer (score 3):

At its core, Spring is a dependency injection framework. This means that instead of doing

```
public class MyService
    private MyDao dao;

    public MyService() {
        dao = new MyDao();
    }
}
```

You can do

```
public class MyService
    private MyDao dao;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(MyDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
}
```

And Spring will automatically call the constructor and inject an instance of MyDao. The main benefit is that the code is easily unit-testable.

On top of that, it allows injecting proxies instead of the actual implementations directly. These proxies will indeed handle the transaction management for you, and more (exception translation, security checks, etc.).

So instead of explicitely opening, committing and rollbacking transactions, you would simply annotate a service method with `@Transactional`, and Spring would open, commit/rollback the transaction. And the transaction context would automatically propagate to the nested service calls.

This short answer is only to give you an idea. To learn more, read about dependency injection, and read the Spring documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use Spring annotations like `@Service` for service classes, `@Repository` for Dao classes and `@Controller` for action controllers. Use of `@Transactional` on service class or methods is suffice to carry out transactions.